# store procedure calling xp_cmdshell

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

After insert Trigger on table calls **Sp1**. Some code before is executed, but when it comes to  EXEC xp_cmdshell it goes to suspend mode (I used sp_who on SQL server). Suspended process is bulk import of some data from csv of NT SERVER\MSQLSERVER.

**Sp1** (Store procedure does some job with SSIS package.)

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell 'c:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /f "C:\xxx\yyy\import_data.dtsx"'
```

**What I have done to solve the problem:**

> 1. Security on xp_cmdshell, user A which is used to connect form app to database is in sysadmin role, xp_cmdshell in enabled. User has execute permissions on xp_cmdshell on master table.
> 2. Tried with sp_cmdshell_proxy_user no luck
> 3. NT service\MSSQLserver has full control over 'c:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\120\DTS\Binn AND C:\xxx

**The best part:)**

When I run **Sp1** from SQL studio with user A it works just fine!

When I run from **app** (the same user A), it goes to suspend. APP is asp.net core.

Any idea where to look? I suspect it is security issue

Comment: Suspended means it is waiting for something, you need to check what your process is waiting for most probably some sort of resource, you can execute `Select SPID , lastwaittype from sys.sysprocesses Where loginame = 'YourLogin'` use your login and see what is the LastWaitType.

Comment: Yes I have LCK_M_X, further analysis is in progress

Comment: So this means your query is trying to obtain exclusive lock on a resource but cant do so because there is already a lock on the resource, find out what object it is and what process has that other lock.

Comment: I run sp in trigger after insert and I think here is the problem. Because if I run SP from sql studio everything works fine…Some commit should do the trick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837265/can-a-ssis-package-called-using-xp-cmdshell-enlist-in-a-sql-server-transaction Here is described same problem as mine..

Comment: ok, problem was with delete statment. Before I run xp_spcmdshell was some delete statment on same table as bulk_insert statmnet